# Svg Object - blank/transparent/white

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to have a svg icon using the object tag. However, it does not display anything.

The SVG files is blank/transparent/white, and it does not seem that there are any data on it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="navbar-brand-cont">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
          <object data="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/logoo.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
          <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/logo.png">
          </object>
     </a>
</div>
```

**Adress:** http://bit.ly/1LTSf5b

**Export settings:**

[image: Export settings]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your PHP code is irrelevant, and actively unhelpful. You should View Source on the browser and show what HTML code your PHP is producing.

Comment: Thank you. But the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing some of the code and exporting in a different way.

The image was blank/transparent/white because of a bug in Illustrator. The export problem was solved by doing the following:

1. Copy the file into a new document
2. Put everything on one layer
3. Export

In the code there was an issue with `navbar-brand-cont` and `navbar-brand`. This problem was solved by doing some minor changes.

Answer (score 1):

The [referenced SVG file](http://www.vekvemedia.no/wp-content/themes/vekvemedia/img/logoo.svg) does not contain anything renderable i.e. it's got no shapes or text, just SVG font definitions.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I have been looking into that too. So you believe there is problem exporting it from Illustrator?

Comment: The question does not contain any information about what you're exporting from illustrator and I'm afraid questions about using illustrator don't belong here anyway as they wouldn't be programming questions. You might see whether you think such a question would be on topic here http://superuser.com/tour

Answer (score -2):

Please, read about the SVG element in HTML and you can achieve it.

http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp

If you include the SVG code it works. Also, read about Räphael that helps you to play with svg objects.

http://raphaeljs.com

Good luck!